# Multiple Host Fragments - Navigation Android Jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to have a multiple host_fragment to have many `bottomNavigationView`. One of the tabs (Nº2 "Myzone") go to another fragment which is my second host_fragment ("profile_host_fragment") it has another `bottomNavigationView` at the top.
What I was trying to do is this:
[image]
main_nav_graph

```
<navigation
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:startDestination="@id/feature_home_nav_graph">
    <include app:graph="@navigation/feature_home_nav_graph" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/feature_my_zone_nav_graph" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/feature_catalogue_nav_graph" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/feature_cart_nav_graph" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/feature_support_nav_graph" />
</navigation>
```

my_zone_nav_graph (where profile tab is)

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/myZoneFragment"
    android:id="@+id/feature_my_zone_nav_graph">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myZoneFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.myzone.MyZoneFragment"
        android:label="fragment_my_zone"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_zone">
   
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myZoneFragment_to_profileHostFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileHostFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileHostFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.ProfileHostFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile_host"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile_host" />

</navigation>
```

profile_nav_graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/addressFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addressFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.address.AddressFragment"
        android:label="fragment_address"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_address" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paymentsFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.payments.PaymentsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_payments"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_payments" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/shippingFragment"
        android:name="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.shipping.ShippingFragment"
        android:label="fragment_shipping"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_shipping" />
</navigation>
```

this is my fragment_profile_host

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.ProfileHostFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/topNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/profile_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profile_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topNavigationView"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/profile_nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and I am trying to set up nav controller on ProfileHostFragment this way like in the same that in `NavHostActivity`

```
  val navController = profile_nav_host_fragment.findNavController()
        topNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Process: game.spa.android.app.v3, PID: 22367
java.lang.IllegalStateException: profile_nav_host_fragment must not be null
    at feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.ProfileHostFragment.setupTopNavigation(ProfileHostFragment.kt:22)
    at feature_my_zone.presentation.profile.ProfileHostFragment.onViewCreated(ProfileHostFragment.kt:17)
```

I Don't know what is the propper way to achieve this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In spite of `profile_nav_host_fragment.findNavController()`, try with NavHost from activity context like `activity.findNavController(R.id.profile_nav_host_fragment)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `IllegalStateException` happens?

Basically, thing is that when we have nested navigation host fragments then retrieving child `NavHost fragment` from **Fragment** class throws this exception. refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/fragment/package-summary#findnavcontroller)

> Official doc states that:
>
> *fun Fragment.findNavController(): NavController*
>
> Calling this on a Fragment that is not a NavHostFragment or within a
>   NavHostFragment will result in an IllegalStateException

---

Solution is to retrieve it from **activity context** and navigation library provides method for that *(refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/package-summary#findnavcontroller))*:

> *fun Activity.findNavController(@IdRes viewId: Int): NavController*
>
> Find a NavController given the id of a View and its containing
>   Activity.
>
> Calling this on a View that is not a NavHost or within a NavHost will
>   result in an IllegalStateException.

So, changing

```
val navController = profile_nav_host_fragment.findNavController()
```

to

```
val navController = activity.findNavController(R.id.profile_nav_host_fragment)
```

will help solving the exception.